# How do I print a string from kernel buffer? Am I using copy_from_user() right?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

Hi I'm writing a write() method for my character driver and I was wondering why when I copy data from the user into my kernel buffer that my buffer contains random jibberish. Bellow is the method that I am using.

```
ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buff, size_t count, loff_t *offp){// This function looks good
    struct my_char_structure *my_dev = filp->private_data;
    char *offset; // This points to my buffer
    size_t np, left_to_print = count; // These are the bytes left to write


//my_dev->set.write is a double pointer to a sentence where
//set.write = array[sentence number][character in sentence]
//set.write if set.write points to non-allocated memory, the sentence number is NULL
//My device only holds 100 sentences in all

    if(my_dev->set.write == NULL){// Write is a double pointer that points
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Device has no more room");
        return -ENOMEM; // Look up
    }


//you can ignore the commented out stuff but I want to check to see if I'm referencing
//a sentence that has been filled out. other wise the sentence is null and may be 
//written to. I will add this to my code later for traversing sentences.
    /*if(*(my_dev->set.write) != NULL){
        my_dev->set.write ++;
        dev_write(filp,buff,count,offp);
        exit 0;

    }*/

    if (down_interruptible(&my_dev->sem))
        return -ERESTARTSYS;

// Here I'm referencing a memory segment that acts as a pointer to a sentence which
//I write to. *(my_dev->set.write) is a pointer to a char buff which I will place chars
// which is essentially my string

    *(my_dev->set.write) = kmalloc(count,GFP_KERNEL);
    offset = *(my_dev->set.write); // my offset points to that buffer as well

//A sentence can only be the size of count, which is passed by the user
//thats why I allocate count bytes for memory.


        if((np = copy_from_user(offset,buff,left_to_print)) < 0)
            goto erro_out;

        left_to_print -= (count-np);
        offset += (count-np);
        offp += (count-np);

//For debbuging purposes I have printk(). My offset points to my buffer, however
//prints jibberish. In user space I insert \0 at the end of the string.

            printk(KERN_ALERT " 4 :: write && left is ... %ld. The string %s", left_to_print, offset); // %s prints jibberish

    return left_to_print; // change to count

    erro_out:// if there was an error I free the sentence so that it may be written to.

        kfree(*(my_dev->set.write));
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Print error %ld",np);
        return -EFAULT; // look this up
}
```

If my method is a bit winded, a summary of my method is shown bellow. This should be good for a first time write to the device.

```
ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buff, size_t count, loff_t *offp){// This function looks good
    struct my_char_structure *my_dev = filp->private_data;
    static char *offset;

    if (down_interruptible(&my_dev->sem))
        return -ERESTARTSYS;

    *(my_dev->set.write) = kmalloc(count,GFP_KERNEL);
    offset = *(my_dev->set.write);

        if(copy_from_user(offset,buff,left_to_print) < 0)
            goto erro_out;

// This is my question, why does %s print jibberish

            printk(KERN_ALERT " 4 :: write && left is ... %ld. The string %s", left_to_print, offset); 

    return 0; // change to count

    erro_out:
        kfree(*(my_dev->set.write));
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Print error %ld",np);
        return -EFAULT; // look this up     
}
```

I use echo "my sentence">/dev/my_dev to write to my device. I don't care if echo works. I just want the printk() to display "my sentence" which means copy_from is working. Also I've tried using echo "my sentence\0">/dev/my_dev to adhere to the rule of sticking null char at the end of string.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `copy_from_user` expects a destination address. By passing it the offset like this:

```
    if((np = copy_from_user(offset,buff,left_to_print)) < 0)
```

You're giving it the wrong address to write to. You should pass your buffer, like:

```
    if((np = copy_from_user(_my_buffer_ + offset,buff,left_to_print)) < 0)
```

Be sure you allocate enough space so you can add the `offset` to the address and note that I'm assuming your buffer is of a data type which `sizeof` evaluates to 1.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this. Initially I set offset = start_of_buffer. I suppose its misleading in the sense that my offset isn't truely my offset but my starting address. I only did that for testing purposes, but I will fix that since you are right and it is not in my original code.

Comment: ok, if you do ``memset(offset, 0, count)``, will garbage be displayed?